# Copy array from state using Array.from() from getter's return is not working on Vuex

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I've a array on my State and I get it with Getter. The problem is that I can't copy these array. I'm trying do it:

```
export default {
data() {
 ...,
 termoSelected: false,
 terms: []
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getPaymentUtils: 'negotiationaccount/getPaymentUtils', // It returns a Array
    })
},
mounted() {
 console.log(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash) // Shows data OK
 this.terms = Array.from(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash)
},
methods: {
 checkBoxChanged (index) { // Caled when checkbox is changed with v-model termoSelected
      this.terms[index].selected = this.termoSelected // Trigger: Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
  }
}

}
```

I tried `.slice()` function too. But not works. So my problem is that when I get the the values from State using Getter I can't copy the array with anyway. How I can solve that problem?

Comment: you are sure that your array is loaded and has value before you trying to copy that array ?

Comment: @AniketPawar yes, I edited with the console that I used to check it

Comment: I don't know vuex, but I'm pretty sure I could answer if you could show what does the array look as JSON or when you log it into console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript and ES6, you can use spread operator, like:

`this.terms = [...this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash]`

But depending on the deep of the objects inside the array, you would need to use something like *deepClone* from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

Comment: not works too... Using cloneDeep: `'_' is not defined (no-undef)`

Comment: So... an ugly way is do `this.terms = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash))` but it should work

Comment: My problem sounds that `mounted()` method is not executed sequencialy

Comment: Your error `'_' is not defined (no-undef)` is because you didn't install and import lodash in your project correctly

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash)) `worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something I use quite often is this:

```
/**
 * Converts array-ish object to iterable.
 * This works with any object that follows these rules:
 *
 *  - `object` has a property `length` which is a positive integer or zero
 *  - for each integer `i` between 0 and `object.length`, there exists a property `object[i]`
 * @template T
 * @param {T[]|HTMLCollectionOf<T>|{length:number, [name:string]:T}} object
 * @returns {IterableIterator<T>}
 */
function* toIterable(object) {
    const l = object.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        yield object[i];
    }
}
```

If `this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash` follows the above rules, that function will give you an iterator for it. Which can be then used for expansion to create a copy:

```
const asArray = [...toIterable(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash)];
```

I usually use it for HTML collections and improperly formatted JSON's. It has the benefit that you can iterate without copying the array, eg:

```
for(const option of toIterable(this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash)) {
    console.log(option);
}
```

If the code above does not work, please update your post with an example of what does `this.getPaymentUtils.rememberOptionsCash` actually look like. From the error it seems you may not be allowed to access the objects inside the array the way you're accessing them.

Comment: This is a Vuex question, you must know vuex's state resource. But basically, I can't copy the array, and your function not works too.